# How zend libs file(Rewrite Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory) class in Magento 2

Tags: overrides, class, zend

i am trying to override Zend libs class like magento2 using **preference**

My di.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory" type="\Codility\Customers\Zend\Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image"/>
</config>
```

But it not override . it hit to core class **Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory**  how can we override zend lib class ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends how it's been written but many of the zend classes you can simple create a new class which extends the old class and reference your new class in code

```
Vendor_Module_Whatever extends Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory
```

Then in code

```
$var = new \Vendor_Module_Whatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the Zend library itself the Magento DI mechanisms don't apply (ie preferences etc won't work). The only invocation that I could find looks like this:

```
    public static function imageWithPath($filePath)
    {
        return Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory($filePath);
```

You would have to move up the calling chain until you are within a Magento class to apply a different preference for it. For example `Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory` used by `Zend_Pdf_Image` used by `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf` (so you'll likely want the concrete class that extend of AbstractPdf)